# Proving that $x^3$ is continuous at $c$ > $0$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$

Tags: real-analysis

Here is my attempt at an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. Can you please confirm if my working is correct? In particular, am I allowed to bound $\delta$ in terms of $c$, the point at which I show f is continuous? If so, is this because $c$ is fixed?

In this context, it suffices to verify that ($\forall$$\epsilon$ > 0) ($\exists$$\delta$ > 0) ($\forall$x: |$x$ $-$ $c$| < $\delta$$\implies$|$x^3$ $-$ $c^3$| < $\epsilon$).

Suppose $c$ > 0. First, bound $\delta$. $\delta$ < c, so that if |$x$ $-$ $c$| < $\delta$, then $x$ > 0. Thus, $cx$ > 0.

|$x^3$ $-$ $c^3$| = |$x$ $-$ $c$||$x^2$ $+$ $cx$ $+$ $c^2$|
< |$x$ $-$ $c$||$x^2$ $+$ $2cx$ $+$ $c^2$| = |$x$ $-$ $c$|$(x + c)^2$

Since $\delta$ < c, if |$x$ $-$ $c$| < $\delta$, then |$x$ $-$ $c$| < $c$, and so $0$ < $x$ < $2c$. Thus,  $(x + c)^2$ < $(2c + c)^2$ = $9c^2$.

So if |$x$ $-$ $c$| < $\delta$ < c, then |$x^3$ $-$ $c^3$| < |$x$ $-$ $c$|$(x + c)^2$ < |$x$ $-$ $c$|$\cdot$$9c^2$.

Therefore, given some $\epsilon$ > 0, a suitable choice for $\delta$ is $\min$ {$c$, $\frac{\epsilon}{9c^2}$}.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proof looks good and clever.

You noticed that since you have $|x^3 - c^3| = |x-c|\,|x^2 + cx + c^2|$, you need only control the size of $|x^2 + cx + c^2|$ term, since $|x-c|$ is controlled by $\delta$. In your proof, you relied heavily on the fact that $c >0$, which is just fine. Alternatively, you could go about it forgetting the sign of $c$ and make an argument such as
$$
|x^2 + xc + c^2| \leq x^2 + c^2 + |x|\,|c|
$$

so with $\delta < 1$ (here $1$ is my favorite, basically arbitrary choice of positive number), if $|x-c| < \delta$ then (by the reverse triangle inequality) $|x| < |c|+1$, so whenever $\delta < 1$ and $|x -c | < \delta$
$$
x^2 + c^2 + |x|\,|c| < (|c|+1)^2 + c^2 + (|c|+1)|c| < 3(|c|+1)^2
$$
and hence you can take $\delta = \min\left( \frac{\epsilon}{3(|c|+1)^2}, 1\right)$.